# cxGrid expand current date which is stored as string in the database

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Regarding this question :
[Have cxGrid expand current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304898/have-cxgrid-expand-current-date)
and the solution:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with cxGrid1DBTableView1 do
  begin
    DataController.DataSource.DataSet.Locate('YourDateFieldName',DateTimeToStr(Date),
    [loPartialKey]);
    ViewData.Records[DataController.FocusedRowIndex].Expand(True);
  end;
end;
```

if "YourDateFieldName" field in the database was string type (date stored as string) how would you pass this to the grid in the above example?

Comment: In provided example you are already looking for string (DateTimeToStr). If you keep data in another format, then you should build corresponding query to search. But what is your problem, did you try this code?

Comment: @Andrei Galatyn - in the above example 'YourDateFieldName' is already Date type so you are converting it to string. I am wondering what happens if the field is "String" already. String to string does not work.

Comment: in example above we can't see what is the type of field "YourDateFieldName", we convert result of Date function to string, not field. Locate with string as param for string field should work, if it doesn't, give us some details what dataset you use, what is the type of the field, ...

Comment: @Andrei Galatyn - Imagine if "YourDateFieldName" was a string field used to store date. How would you convert string to date in the above case?